# KeystoneJS app failing to deploy on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine, keystonejs

I have a KeystoneJS app on a Google Compute Engine instance, after executing mongod and npm start in my project folder, I run gcloud app deploy and get the following error:

```
Mongoose connection "error" event fired with:
{ MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect
at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:326:35)
at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Connection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:272:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:175:49)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
name: 'MongoError',
message:
'failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect' }
Error: KeystoneJS (Modern Marketing) failed to start - Check that you are running `mongod` in a separate process.
at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/keystone/lib/core/openDatabaseConnection.js:59:10)
at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:182:13)
at Immediate.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:296:19)
at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! modern-marketing@0.0.0 start: `node keystone.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the modern-marketing@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-01-02T05_59_39_493Z-debug.log
```

I don't have much experience with MongoDB or KeystoneJS, so any insight is appreciated

Comment: You say its on Compute Engine, but you are running App Engine commands. Can you clarify what product you are actually using? They are two very different products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that while deploying to GAE, you're keeping the default connection to a local hosted mongo database. (`failed to connect to server [localhost:27017]`)

Since GAE environment doesn't have mongodb running, you have to create a mongo database (there are many different mongodb services that you could use here) and set your project up with `MONGO_URI` env variable.

Keystonejs will then try to connect the database you set in this variable.

I hope this comment will help you, if you still have some issues setting all that stuff up, you can show us your app.yaml file ;)